# How to create clickable links for foreign keys in Django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How to make foreign keys clickable in Django admin list view to open related detail admin page?

Currently, Django admin displays foreign keys as plain text in the list view. Is there a way to make these foreign keys clickable links that direct users to the related detail admin page upon clicking? For example on clicking on payment number it should take the user to payment details admin page, where payment is foreign key of Order model.

How can this be implemented?

[image: image of Django admin dashboard with foreign key as just a text filed]

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('pk',)
    list_display = ['pk', 'user', 'order_date', 'deadline', 'status', 'payment', 'total', 'debt', 'shipping']
    list_filter = ['status', 'if_extended']
    exclude = ['order_date', 'deadline', 'return_date', 'total', 'payment', 'shipping', 'if_extended', 'number_of_extensions']
    search_fields = ('pk',)
    inlines = [ItemInline]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = [
        'pk',
        'user',
        'order_date',
        'deadline',
        'status',
        'payment_link', # changed this 
        'total',
        'debt',
        'shipping',
     ]

    def payment_link(self, obj):
        related_obj = obj.payment
        url = reverse('admin:myapp_payment_change', args=[related_obj.id])  # replace 'myapp' with your app name
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, related_obj)

    payment_link.short_description = 'Payment'
```